# Between condition on mysql varchar field

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on property development site. there are two price for property one is from price and another one is to price.

I am storing it as varchar field with hyphen like this :- 25000-30000.

While searching for the record I'd used between condition for the price like this  `where price between 5000 AND 25000`.

After executing this query it returns me the property who is having exact price. I am not able to get the between result.

Comment: can show your query?

Comment: Are these both prices stored in separate columns?

Comment: the column is one name as price SELECT * from tbl_property where price between '0' AND '100000'

Comment: you use LIKE  for get matching value

Comment: how to use LIKE operator as there are two prices min and max. Can u pls show me example?

Comment: Why would you want to store the price range like that? The two prices should be stores in two differen int or decimal fields. That would make the database queries much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here you will need to differentiate 2 values by **-** and treat them
>   as mathematical values rather than char. So your query will be like
>   this.

```
SELECT * from tbl_property WHERE price between 5000 AND 25000 OR ( CAST( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  price,  '-', 1 ) AS UNSIGNED ) between 5000 AND 25000 ) OR ( CAST( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  price,  '-', -1 ) AS UNSIGNED )  between 5000 AND 25000 )
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks very much for your kind reply. Sorry i forgot to thanks u because i was busy in moving the things to live. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to split the price and check if the value is greater than or equal to the lower limit and less or equal to upper limit. Like this

```
SELECT * from tbl_property where SUBSTRING_INDEX(property_price, '-', 1) >= 0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(property_price, '-', -1) <= 100000
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I really appreciate it.